# Cheese cannot detect webcam

Tags: linux, usb, webcam

When I connect my "Philips spc315nc/00" webcam the `Cheese` app does not allow me to select a webcam from the preferences, it is grayed out, as if no devices were connected. The thing is that the `usb-devices` command recognizes it, and appart from that, I can see the output in `VLC` correctly.

Why does this happen and how can I make cheese 'understand' the webcam? Does this mean that `VLC` has more supported cams than `Cheese`?

EDIT:

Running `xawtv -hwscan` gives me

```
This is xawtv-3.103, running on Linux/x86_64 (4.15.0-20-generic)
looking for available devices
port 537-568
    type : Xvideo, image scaler
    name : NV17 Video Texture

/dev/video0: OK                         [ -device /dev/video0 ]
    type : libv4l
    name : SPC315NC       
    flags:  capture
```

so I guess the driver supports v4l.

Comment: Does its driver support V4L2?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams It uses the gspca_zc3xx driver

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams And the driver is active.